# CSS Rem: same width and height, but result is not equal

Tags: css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.icon-del {
  width: 0.37333rem;
  height: 0.37333rem;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/28x28) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-del"></div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

You can see that, when rem convert to css, width and height not equal.

Comment: Your image shows `.icon-del`, but code is for `.box`... Also `html` has invalid rule `font-size: ` (it's empty)

Comment: @Justinas sorry~ fixed~

Comment: This SASS compiler makes same sizes, maybe some other CSS? https://gist.github.com/justux90/a41217695b4114c988dbce7f89c0aa98

Comment: @caramba `icon.scss:1` - *SASS*

Comment: @Justinas thank you! Didn't see that

Comment: @Justinas ye, it compile the same, but browser calc not the same~ you can see the screenshot, the value is 20.922x23.891

Comment: @newbie Setting CSS dimensions does not mean that inner content can't expand element. Maybe you have some bigger elements inside?

Comment: can you simply provide a minimal demo showing the problem?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I try to rebuild it again, and I think some thing wrong with my code... :P

Comment: What browser (and system) are you testing this on? I'm seeing height and width matching (both 23.891) in Safari and Chrome (Mac).

Comment: @Justinas Hmmmmmm~  It looks like some thing wrong with my code~ :P

Comment: @AlexMagill Mac Chrome, use web inspector device simulator iPhone X(5, 6, 7 and etc.)

Comment: @newbie It's the size of your background image that's causing the problem - I'd guess it's not square. You can set background-size to cover - which will crop the image within the box making the result square, or add a background colour, perhaps matching one in the image, or, alternatively, re-export the image as a square.

Comment: @AlexMagill What? Since when `background-image` expands element? I think you are missing something

Comment: @Justinas - you're quite right. My mistake - I was confusing the visual appearance with the transparent div that surrounds it.

Comment: @Justinas @AlexMagill @SebastianBrosch @caramba Hi~ I found that it my fault~ I use flex layout and it auto resize the `.icon-del` dimenssions... :P Thanks~

Comment: @newbie This was exactly my problem, thank you. I solved it by using min-height and min-width for my svg CSS that was inside a flex container. This prevents the flex from smushing it :)